# Multiple Calls on a Single method in rust

Tags: rust

I am writing a library in rust which builds a self-referential data
structure; it uses indexes internally for nodes which are actually
identified by URIs (or IRIs which is the same thing).

I have a method like so:

```
fn iri(self, s: String)-> IRI
```

IRI is actually just a type alias for usize:

```
struct IRI(usize)
```

so that I can do this, where `ont` is the main data structure:

```
let i = ont.iri("http://example.com");
```

I can then pass this to further methods:

```
let c = ont.class(i);
```

This is okay, but I'd like to combine these into one line:

```
let c = ont.class(ont.iri("http://example.com"))
```

This fails because I can't borrow the reference to `ont` twice. Both the `iri` and `class` calls are mutable and need to be.

Is there any way of achieving this without an intermediate variable?

Comment: Have you tried defining `iri` as `fn iri(&self, s: String) -> IRI` and `class` similarly? Note that Rust doesn't borrow by default, so that might be your issue.

Comment: Both methods change the `ont` data structure unfortunately, so need to borrow mutably. I've added clarification to the question.

Comment: `IRI` is not a type alias - it's a wrapper struct. A type alias would be `type IRI = usize`.

Comment: There is no way of working around this. The reasons are given in the accepted answer to the question you yourself linked above.